# React Native [NativeBase] - Why nothing is shown inside Content?

Tags: react-native, native-base

I was experimenting with NativeBase and it does some weird things.

I'm trying to display a red square on screen (full-screen), but it does nothing.

Obviously this is easy working with pure react-native built-in components.

But it doesn't work working with NativeBase.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Button
} from 'react-native';
import {
  Container,
  Content
} from 'native-base';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onButtonClick = this.onButtonClick.bind(this);
  }

  onButtonClick() {
    console.log("The button has been pressed!");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content>
          <View 
            style={styles.container}
          />
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#FF0000',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
  }
});
```

And this is what I'm getting:
[image]

Why is that? According to the docs, whilst working with NativeBase everything should be wrapped within the Container component. And every container should have **only** one content component.

Being the content component the entire screen, inside this content component I added a view which I set `flex: 1` and made it `width: '100%', height: '100%', background: '#FF0000'`.

Why is it not showing anything? It should show an entire red screen.

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `<Content>` is a `ScollView` of React Native so you can use `contentContainerStyle`.

So:

```
<Content contentContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#FF0000" }}>
```

> [Reference one](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/1158#issuecomment-322673896)
>
> [Reference two](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#contentcontainerstyle)